# Слайдер на wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, cms

Недавно начал учить Wordpress,  но сейчас столкнулся с  такой проблемой:
HTML посадил,  сделал слайдер на основе библиотеки slick slider,  но не могу понять как добавлять фотографии в слайдер через админку. Прошу знающих подсказать на примере или как правильно гуглить. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score -1):

WordPress изначально ничего не знает о вашем слайдере.

Поставьте плагин [Slick Slider](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-slick-slider-and-image-carousel/#description).

Или почитайте о том, как [создавать свои настройки в админке](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html).